# Vue components css background-image path error

Tags: vue.js, webpack-2, vue-loader

output

```
    output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 
        config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
        filename: '[name].js'
    }
```

base

```
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: './',
    productionSourceMap: false,
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css']
  },
```

after build,the index pages work normal, css background-image path like this

```
background: url(./static/img/bg_certificate.c5cad1e.png) no-repeat 50%;
```

but the component css background-image path error, like this

```
background: url(static/img/btn_my.b9186cc.png) no-repeat 50%;
```

It's look like the path lose "./",

Comment: I am having similar issue. When I set build:{ assetsPublicPath: './'} my dist css file still build to "url(static/img"

Comment: Are you using the `css-loader` plugin?

Answer (score 10):

I also come by this issue when I tried using styles in component of Vue 3. I solved it by using the following syntax.

```
background-image: url('~@/assets/image.png');
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of absolute path, You should give the relative path from the current file location with webpack in .vue file, something like:

```
background: url(../../static/img/btn_my.b9186cc.png) no-repeat 50%;
```

Comment: I've been running "npm run build" with different assetsPublicPath: values and for some reason "./" will not create in my css a relative path in the ```background-image: url(./static/img)``` like so...only ```url(static/img)```

Comment: @AkinHwan possible to create a basic template of your code having this issue and put that on Github for us to play and fix this?

Answer (score 6):

What about setting:

```
build: {
  ...
  assetsSubDirectory: '',
  assetsPublicPath: '/static/',
  ...
}
```

and so:

```
background: url(/static/img/btn_my.b9186cc.png) no-repeat 50%;
```

Working with relative paths is, in general lines, a [nightmare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395641/vuejs-difficulties-to-build-with-relative-path).

Answer (score 4):

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + require('@/assets/bg3.jpg') + '\')' }
```

This will be the Best solution for the background image.

Comment: You mixed some react syntax here... Vue would be something like:

:style=" `background-image: url(${require('@/assets/bg3.jpg')}) ` "

Comment: This "require" was the real solution for me, very thanks.