# How to pass images url through props in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

For some reason it is not working, is this correct?

Parent Component:

```html
<achievement-post imgURL="../assets/ach1.jpg"></achievement-post>

<script>
import achievementPost from "../components/AchievementPost.vue";

// ...
</script>
```

Child component:

```html
<template>
 <img :src="imgURL" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    imgURL: String
  },
    // ...
}
</script>
```

When I hardcode the URL it works, so I'm not sure what is going on. Please help.

Comment: The solution for me, was in the [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737568/vue-components-css-background-image-path-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737568/vue-components-css-background-image-path-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Webpack, there is no way for it to track the image module dependency with a string url prop, so it will not try and resolve it.

The solution is to require it with an expression.

> A context is created if your request contains expressions, so the
>   exact module is not known on compile time.

Child component:

```
<template>
 <img :src="require(`../assets/${imgURL}`)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    imgURL: String
  },
    // ...
}
</script>
```

Parent component

```
<achievement-post imgURL="ach1.jpg"></achievement-post>

<script>
import achievementPost from "../components/AchievementPost.vue";

// ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes are case insensitive: You should avoid using capital letters in props names. Maybe it's the cause of your problem.

```
<achievement-post img_url="../assets/ach1.jpg"></achievement-post>
```

And

```
 export default {
      props: {
        img_url: String
      },
        // ...
    }
```

You can see it at the bottom of this page:
https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/
or at the top of this page:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html