# Vue cli 2 local font - module not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, fonts

I'm trying to use my own local font in my vue cli 2 small project.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "ALMONI";
      src: local("ALMONI"),
      url(../public/fonts/ALMONI-700.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

and than use it that way in the same scoped style tag

```
html,
body {
  font-family: "ALMONI";
}
```

than I got this error (module is not found)

```
This relative module was not found:

* ../public/fonts/ALMONI-700.ttf in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: this should solve your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737568/vue-components-css-background-image-path-error

Comment: @CosimoChellini  I've already use a relative path like they have recommended, also for me it's not a build error action.