# vuejs: relative paths not being added in build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build

I seem to be having difficulty getting my vue js app to run from the dist folder.

I look around this site and found this: [Vuejs, Difficulties to build with relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395641/vuejs-difficulties-to-build-with-relative-path) which gives this solution:

1. Create a "vue.config.js" file at the main path of your project
2. Give a relative path. Example:

```
    module.exports = {
        publicPath: './'
    };
```

Which I have followed. But when I run

```
npm run build
```

and check the file, it is not adding that in.

If it helps here is my version info

> "core-js": "^2.6.5",
>
> "vue": "^2.6.10"

Anyone else had this issue or can provide a solution?

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the public path that webpack builds by adding this little bit of code to your main.js.

`__webpack_public_path__ = 'whatever/path/you/want/to/set/at/runtime'`

Webpack create a `.p` variable in your build files, which has a default value of `"/"` .   so anything you assign to the variable above, will overwrite this and assign whatever prefix you want, in your case `"./"`

This information comes from https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2944

Comment: Hi, I've created a vue.config.js with publicPath: './'. However, relative paths not being added in build. Ex: <link href=css/app.a3662c38.css rel=preload as=style><link href=css/chunk-vendors.d95e1e17.css rel=preload as=style>
I want the './' to be added before. I'm using @vue/cli 4.3.1. Thanks